# How to disable QML Debugger in Qt Creator entirely?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

How can I disable QML debugging in QtC entirely? I can disable it from the run settings, but for some reason it is always switched (back) on.

I do not use QML in the UI, but I use the JavaScript engine for other purposes (pure guess, is that why it is always "on"?). But I entirely want to disable QML debugging, as this always "hangs" and is not needed (at my place).

How can I do that?

[image: QML Debugger]

I can uncheck "Enable QML" but is always checked "on" again when I restart QtC.

Comment: try to  CONFIG -= qml_debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the option **Enable QML debugging and profiling** from the **Build Steps** in the **Build Settings**

Comment: Good point, see there is an option in build as well, will that cause the same as `CONFIG -= qml_debug `

Answer (score 0):

Just some details:

You are correct it is here, when I check QML `CONFIG+=qml_debug` is added to the cmd line. Wonder if the `CONFIG-=qml_debug` in the `.pro` reverts that(the idea is good)

`P:.....in\qmake.exe H:\Pr...pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" && P:/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/jom.exe qmake_all`

[image: QML debug]